# Maxheap vs priorityqueue confusion

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, max-heap, minmax-heap

Suppose we want to sort a hashmap based on the value. We implement a priorityQueue with comparator to do this. As a result, the resulting pq is sorting from the largest to the smallest from index 0 to end.

Here is the code:

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> pq = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>(
                new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
                        return o2.getValue() - o1.getValue();
                    }
                });
```

However, somebody said that it is a maxheap, I understand that heap is just parent value greater than child value but I cannot understand why it is a maxheap? It is just implementing the comparator in a priorityQueue? How does this relates to heap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internal structure of a priority queue in java is heap.
This comparator will be used to compare with the parent value in priority queue.